# React-Native | Fill empty space between rounded object

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have this situation: two aligned `View` with rounded border like the following image:
[image]

At this [link](https://snack.expo.io/T5Ym8s6t5) you can find an example of the code and the situation.
How can I fill the white space between the two object?

Comment: Unless you remove `borderRadius` and possibly all the border from the first View, I don't see any way to 'fill' the gap.

Comment: @blaz Why do you say that? You say that even using a CSS-style way you can not solve?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by 'fill' the white space between the two objects I assume you're asking how to make the border radius flush?

If so you can see it on [this snack link](https://snack.expo.io/0Qygmjdr!)

If not, then could you further explain what you mean?

Comment: No, the white space that I mean are the white triangle with curved side that are created positioning the red object near the white object. I update the image in my answers, are circled in green